# React/Redux App stops processing MapDispatchToProps functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, axios

So Im having an issue with a react/redux project. The program stops outputting information when the first onSetTechnicianXXX call is made. The interesting thing is I successfully perform multiple onSetGetData actions as well as an onSetTechnicianId (inside the parent file). I get no errors. Below is the debug code:

```
console.log("1");
const technician = fetchedTechnicians[0];
console.log("Tech.Intake.Name: " + technician.intakeData.name);
console.log("2");
const name = technician.intakeData.name;
console.log("Name: " + name);
this.onSetTechnicianName(name);
console.log("3");
this.onSetTechnicianName(technician.intakeData.name);
console.log("4");
this.onSetTechnicianCerts(technician.intakeData.certifications);
console.log("5");
this.onSetTechnicianPhone(technician.intakeData.phone);
console.log("6");
this.onSetTechnicianEmail(technician.intakeData.email);
console.log("7");
this.onSetTechnicianServicebay(technician.intakeData.servicebay);
console.log("8");
```

========Output from the Chrome DevTools Console========

```
1                                   TechnicianEditForm.js:118
Tech.Intake.Name: Joe Technician    TechnicianEditForm.js:120
2                                   TechnicianEditForm.js:121
Name: Joe Technician                TechnicianEditForm.js:123
```

========Output from the Chrome Redux DevTool=========

```
selectedTechnicianId(pin): "-LnECtv2Ms40OaFBu2t0"
getdata(pin): false
name(pin): ""
certifications(pin): ""
phone(pin): ""
email(pin): ""
servicebay(pin): ""
```

These are the React/Redux files for processing the state
===========actionTypes.js:==========================

```
export const SET_TECHNICIANID = 'SET_TECHNICIANID';
export const SET_GETDATA = 'SET_GETDATA';
export const SET_TECHNICIAN_NAME = 'SET_TECHNICIAN_NAME';
export const SET_TECHNICIAN_CERTS = 'SET_TECHNICIAN_CERTS';
export const SET_TECHNICIAN_PHONE = 'SET_TECHNICIAN_PHONE';
export const SET_TECHNICIAN_EMAIL = 'SET_TECHNICIAN_EMAIL';
export const SET_TECHNICIAN_SERVICEBAY = 'SET_TECHNICIAN_SERVICEBAY';
```

=================actions.js:===========================

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const setTechnicianId = (selectedTechnicianId) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_TECHNICIANID,
        selectedTechnicianId: selectedTechnicianId
    };
};
export const setGetData = (getdata) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_GETDATA,
        getdata: getdata
    };
};
export const setTechnicianName = (name) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_TECHNICIAN_NAME,
        name: name
    };
};
##### Others Not Shown But Simular #####
```

=================reducer.js:================

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';
import { updateObject } from './utility';

const initialState = {
    selectedTechnicianId: '',
    getdata: false,
    name: '',
    certifications: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    servicebay: ''
}

const baseReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SET_TECHNICIANID:
            return updateObject(state, { selectedTechnicianId: action.selectedTechnicianId });
        case actionTypes.SET_GETDATA:
            return updateObject(state, { getdata: action.getdata });
        case actionTypes.SET_TECHNICIAN_NAME:
            return updateObject(state, { name: action.name });
##### Others Not Shown But Simular #####
```

=======================index.js:=====================

```
export {
    setTechnicianId,
    setGetData,
    setTechnicianName,
    setTechnicianCerts,
    setTechnicianPhone,
    setTechnicianEmail,
    setTechnicianServicebay,
} from './actions';
```

===========Part of the TechnicianEditForm.js============

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        selectedTechnicianId: state.selectedTechnicianId,
        getdata: state.getdata,
        name: state.name,
        certifications: state.certifications,
        phone: state.phone,
        email: state.email,
        servicebay: state.servicebay
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onSetTechnicianId: (selectedTechnicianId) => dispatch(actionTypes.setTechnicianId(selectedTechnicianId)),
        onSetGetData: (getdata) => dispatch(actionTypes.setGetData(getdata)),
        onSetTechnicianName: (name) => dispatch(actionTypes.setTechnicianName(name)),
        onSetTechnicianCerts: (certifications) => dispatch(actionTypes.setTechnicianCerts(certifications)),
        onSetTechnicianPhone: (phone) => dispatch(actionTypes.setTechnicianPhone(phone)),
        onSetTechnicianEmail: (email) => dispatch(actionTypes.setTechnicianEmail(email)),
        onSetTechnicianServicebay: (servicebay) => dispatch(actionTypes.setTechnicianServicebay(servicebay)),
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(TechnicianEditForm), axios);
```

Comment: Can you show us where you call the code from the first snippet?

Comment: How are you importing `actionTypes` in `TechnicianEditForm.js`? Shouldn't these calls be similar to `dispatch(actions.setTechnicianName(name))` instead of `actionTypes.setTechnicianName` since if `actionTypes` is the import from `actionTypes.js`, `setTechnicianName` will be undefined.

Comment: azund: actionTypes are in the actions.js file imported at the top of the TechnicianEditForm file. Remember two other actions, setTechnicianId and setGetData are constructed just like the setTechnicianName action and do set and retrieve their values successfully. actionTypes are imported as:
                        import * as actionTypes from '../../../../store/index';